# Left-justifying text under image with max-width:100%

Tags: html, css

I'd like the text under this image to be left justified under the image ('my title' to be aligned with the left side of the image), no matter what it's height, *without* Javascript.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="img-container">
        <img src="http://img.thesun.co.uk/multimedia/archive/01572/empire-state-build_1572000a.jpg"/>

        <div class="info">
            <h1>my title</h1>
            <p> my description</p>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container{
    width:900px;
    position:relative;
}

.img-container{
    text-align:center;
}

img{
    max-width:100%;
}

.info{
    text-align:left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NGwdc/

If you adjust .container width, it should always be aligned to the left side of that image.

Is this possible with only CSS?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to make the image container `display:inline-block`, and the outer-most container `text-align:center`

http://jsfiddle.net/NGwdc/1/